# Trouble with GitHub and ssh keys?

Tags: linux, macos, github, darwin

From one of my hosts I can authenticate with ssh to GitHub, from another I cannot `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`

I was having some issues from my Mac creating a new repo and pushing to it, I always got a permission denied error. However from my Linux host it worked fine.

I checked the repos for deploy keys (in case this was causing the issue), none of my repos had a deploy key set.
I checked the keys on GitHub and there was only one ssh key installed.  I deleted this key and tested, as expected the repos from the Linux host could not connect, yet the Mac could still connect.

From the Mac:
`ssh -T git@github.com Hi mcdent/blog1! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access. bash-3.2$`

From Linux:
`[mike@docker1 doing]$ ssh -T git@github.com git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). [mike@docker1 doing]$`

I'm puzzled as to how the Mac is still authenticating? I likely did have a repo called blog1 in the past but I certainly don't now.
Ideally I'd like to have a single key used on GitHub, which I can use with both my Linux and MacOS hosts.

Any pointers very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm puzzled as to how the Mac is still authenticating?

Then try a `ssh -Tv git@github.com`.
You will see which key file is accessed and used for this authentication.
It should be a private key whose public key is registered to your account.

Check your environment variables or `git config --global` / `git config --system -l` for anything including `blog1`.